# When passing multiple variables in Express GET request only the first variable shows up in the reqest.query

Tags: node.js, firebase, express

I am running into an issue with express in node.js. My server side code has an endpoint to parse a user signup. The request hits a signup endpoint with multiple user parameters. Here is a curl request to hit my express signup.

`curl http://127.0.0.1:5003/cloud-medic/us-central1/app/signup?email=express&password=asdf&firstName=asdf&lastName=asdf&gender=Male&birthDate=1706763600000`

The server side code as I mentioned uses express to handle this GET request. I created an app file to house the express request and firebase configuration.

```
var functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { getDatabase, ref, set, child, push, update } = require("firebase/database");
const { getFirestore, Timestamp, FieldValue, Filter } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
const { initializeApp } =  require('firebase-admin/app');
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');

const firebaseConfig = {
  //CONFIG INFO
}

const admin = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(admin);

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

var router = express.Router();

exports.db = db;
exports.app = app;//functions.https.onRequest(app);
exports.admin = admin;
```

Here is the index file with routing functionality. It defines signup function call.

```
var user = require('./user');
var functions = require("firebase-functions");
const { db, admin, app } = require('./app');

app.get('/signup', function (request, response) {
    console.log("THIS IS A GET FUNCTION");
    console.log(request.query);

    user.signup(request, response);

});
```

When I hit the signup endpoint with the above curl request I get the following req.query object

```
{ email: 'express' }
```

All of the other get request url parameters are not passed, just the first one (email). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you manually sending `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers **and** using the `cors()` middleware which already does that for you?

Comment: Remaoved the CORS headers.  Am still having the same problem I wrote about.

Answer (score 1):

My express code was not my problem. Rather I made a mistake in the curl command. I forgot to include the get request in quotations.

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5003/cloud-medic/us-central1/app/signup?email=express&password=asdf&firstName=asdf&lastName=asdf&gender=Male&birthDate=1706763600000'
```

I hope if you stumble across this post, my mistake leads you to an answer to your question.